# Using union multiple times with distinct on top of the final results

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct, union

I cannot figure out how to merge 4 different columns from 2 different tables together into just one single column of all possible results, with duplicates removed. The actual names are different, but suppose I have the following two tables

**Table1**

1. Field1
2. Field2
3. SomethingElse

**Table2**

1. Field1
2. Field2
3. SomethingElse

Now in the end, I would like to merge all 4 of these fields together into one large field, and then use *distinct* on top of that to eliminate any duplicates, as there are many of them. The final result should be just one single column containing every possible value found in all 4 columns, without any duplicated.

When I was working with just one single table with two fields, I had it working fine:

```
select distinct(Field1) from Table1 where SomethingElse = SomeVal
union
(select distinct(Field2) from Table1 where SomethingElse = SomeVal)
order by 1
```

(of course I wished to have run `distinct` around the final result rather than each field)

Now I needed to add 2 more fields from another table. Nothing I have tried has even run, can't get the syntax right.

Comment: Have you tried something like `select distinct ... from t1 union select ... from t2 union ...`, i.e. only one `distinct` on the first select?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
select distinct val
from ((select field1 as val from table1 where somethingelse = someval) union all
      (select field2 from table1 where somethingelse = someval) union all
      (select field1 from table2 where somethingelse = someval) union all
      (select field2 from table2 where somethingelse = someval)
     ) t
```

I combine the subqueries using `union all` and then only do the `distinct` once on the outer level.

Since the next thing I would want to know is where these values are being used, here is the query for that:

```
select val, SUM(t1f1), SUM(t1f2), SUM(t2f1), SUM(t2f2)
from ((select field1 as val, 1 as t1f1, 0 as t1f2, 0 as t2f1, 0 as t2f2 from table1 where somethingelse = someval) union all
      (select field2, 0 as t1f1, 1 as t1f2, 0 as t2f1, 0 as t2f2 from table1 where somethingelse = someval) union all
      (select field1, 0 as t1f1, 0 as t1f2, 1 as t2f1, 0 as t2f2 from table2 where somethingelse = someval) union all
      (select field2, 0 as t1f1, 0 as t1f2, 0 as t2f1, 1 as t2f2 from table2 where somethingelse = someval)
     ) t
group by val
```

Comment: Shouldn't `as val` be in all 4 of the statements? Or just the first one?

Comment: @JerryDodge . . . What you suggest is good practice but not necessary. The first subquery in a union defines the column names.  In this case, I was just saving on typing.

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct(Field1) from 
(
select Field1 [Field1] from Table1 where SomethingElse = SomeVal
union all
select Field2 [Field1] from Table1 where SomethingElse = SomeVal
) rawResults
order by 1
```

Something like that should work.  Just union together your selects and put that in an in-line view and put your distinct and order by on the outside.  I used union all since you are going to do a distinct once on the outside anyway